# Laravel, I got syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: laravel

I have a method like this

```
function manage(Request $params) {
   $orderBy = $params->order;
   $show = function($filter) {
      switch ($filter) {
         case 'published':
            return 1;
            break;
         case 'draft':
            return 2;
            break;
         case 'pending':
            return 0;
            break;
         default :
            return false;
      }
   }

   $this->pagination = $params->pagination ?? 10;

   if (Auth::id() == 1) {
      $post = Post::where('status', $show($params->show) ?? true)
                  ->orderBy($orderBy ?? 'created_at')                
                  ->paginate(10);

   } else {

      $post = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->where('status', $show($params->show) ?? true)
                  ->orderBy($orderBy ?? 'created_at')                
                  ->paginate(10);

   }

   return view('dashboard.post.manage')->with(['post' => $post]);
}
```

And i got error like this

```
syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)
```

I feeling the error near at `$this->pagination = $params->pagination ?? 10;`

I already check the code, but i couldnt find the error, please check my code

Comment: Add semicolon after function that returns `$show` value.

Comment: Thanks, thats works :), i not focus after 8 hours work but the deadline